# What's the difference between np.array(int) and np.array([int])?

Tags: python, numpy

What's the difference between `np.array(100)` and `np.array([100])`? I understand that the latter is a 1D array containing a single value (`100`) but what is the former called?

Comment: former is 0-d array

Comment: The difference is the `shape`, `()` and `(1,)`, and as a result `ndim`, `0` and `1`.

Comment: Interesting. Its like an integer that follows the array protocol. So, a 0 dimensional point?

Answer (score 3):

This is a 0d array.  It can be used in many of the same ways as other arrays, subject of course to shape and dtype compatibilites.

```
In [545]: x=np.array(3)
In [546]: x.shape
Out[546]: ()          # empty tuple
In [547]: x.ndim
Out[547]: 0
In [548]: x.ravel()
Out[548]: array([3])         # as with other arrays, ravel makes a 1d array
In [549]: x.reshape(1,1,1)    # reshape to 3d
Out[549]: array([[[3]]])
In [550]: x.item()            # extracting that element
Out[550]: 3
In [551]: x[()]               # another extracting
Out[551]: 3             
In [552]: type(_)
Out[552]: numpy.int64
In [553]: type(x.item())
Out[553]: int
```

There's a subtle difference between `item()` and `[()]`.  One returns python object, the other a "numpy scalar".

More on numpy scalars:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#methods

A common case where we encounter 0d array is when an object gets wrapped in an array, such as via `np.save`.

```
In [556]: d = np.array({'foo':'bar'})
In [557]: d
Out[557]: array({'foo': 'bar'}, dtype=object)
In [558]: d.shape
Out[558]: ()
In [559]: d.item()['foo']
Out[559]: 'bar'
```

---

The value of a 0d array can be changed

```
In [562]: x[...] = 4
In [563]: x
Out[563]: array(4)
```